# Prompting the user for permission - facebook developer toolkit

Tags: c#, api, facebook

I am building a small facebook application in c#. I want to prompt the user for permission to post short story feeds to his profile. When I try using the facebook developer toolkit with the following command (in order to see if the permission is already in place):

API.permissions.checkAvailableApiAccess(API.ApplicationKey)

I get error 100 (not even written in facebook's wiki)

Does any of you know how to fix this, and ofcourse how to prompt the user with the approperiate premission request?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to authenticate your app and user on facebook using OAuth.
Try looking at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/.
Using oAuth you can authenticate a user and ask him the permissions to operate with facebook API.